# Executable searching for the linked library in different path than the one set using LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries, linker-errors, dynamic-linking, vxworks

I am building a C++ application using CMake. This application is supposedly to be run on VxWorks OS. This application needs a shared library which is built externally and imported to the project.

I have linked the library to the application as shown below:

```
set(MYLIB_PATH"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../my/lib/}")
add_library(MYLIB SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET MYLIB PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${MYLIB_PATH}/libmylib.so)

target_link_libraries(MyApplication PUBLIC MYLIB)
```

I am able to build the application successfully. Now, I am placing the binaries on the AARCH64 target. Below is my target directory structure:

```
work
    ├── bin
    └── lib
```

I have placed the application in *bin* and the library in *lib*.
When I try to execute the application, I get error that says:

```
--> cannot open "/home/k271k9/workspace/software/apps/../../my/lib/libmylib.so"
```

I did export the environment `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:../lib` , I verified this by using `ldd` command and also other libraries that I am linking are correctly linked from the lib directory.

Is there something wrong in what I am doing?

How can I make the application to find the the library in the lib path. & can someone explain why is the executable looking for the library in the local path where I built the application?

Comment: "I verified this by using `ldd` command" - So, what exactly outputs `ldd` for your executable? Please, add that output to the question post.

Comment: Sorry, I verified the same in using `ldd` command x86 environment and everything was fine. In VxWorks environment `ldd` command is not supported even though it is a flavored posix os.
Both x86 and vxwork binaries are built using same repo though.

Comment: Once again, please, **add output** of `ldd` to your **question post**. I guess that NOT "everything was fine". It smells like the whole path `/home/k271k9/workspace/software/apps/../../my/lib/libmylib.so` becomes SONAME of the `mylib.so` library. The output of `ldd` could shed a light on this aspect.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something wrong in what I am doing?

Yes. There are two problems:

- Your *actual* link command has this argument `/home/k271k9/workspace/software/apps/../../my/lib/libmylib.so`, and
- the library does not have `SONAME` in it.

Given these two conditions, the linker hard-codes the absolute path to the library into your executable as a `NEEDED` entry, and your executable will look for that library at the above path (and *only* at the above path).

Step 1: verify the statements above:

- look at the actual link command
- run  `readelf -d /home/k271k9/workspace/software/apps/../../my/lib/libmylib.so | grep SONAME` (should produce no output).
- run `readelf -d your_binary | grep NEEDED` (should show the absolute path: `/home/k271k9/.../libmylib.so`).

Step 2: fix the problems.

If you are building the `libmylib.so` yourself, adding `-Wl,-soname,libmylib.so` will add `SONAME` tag to it, and then everything else will just work™.

Also, linking with `/path/to/libmylib.so` is ill-advised. It is nearly always better to link with `-L/path/to -lmylib` instead. Doing this will *also* solve your problem (without adding `SONAME`).